# AVR or PIC using MATLAB?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

AVR or PIC,which one is better? Using MATLAB as assembly language. (I am a beginner)

Answer (score 2):

AVR vs PIC? big question, answer depends on application.  search SO and you'll find several opinions.

MATLAB compiles to C.  you can compile C to whatever assembly language you want, AVR and PIC have different ones.  Personally, I've done MATLAB to C to PIC, it was painful to get running, but automated now, and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I found AVR chips and tools are easier to use, but PIC were much cheaper and more common. Both have their OWN assembly language.

You can get C compilers that compile down to both assembly languages. I'm not sure if MATLAB will though, last time I used it MATLAB was I high level Math language.

Answer (score 0):

According to me AVR is better...I done my mostly projects on AVR...

Matlab have support for Arduino for programming AVR with simulink model.we use same for programming Normal AVR board. I've done MATLAB to C to AVR. I have not idea about assembly in Matlab,but there is no problem with that because you can compile C to whatever assembly language you want...

I just give you my opinion that AVR is better because I mostly used AVRs in my project...I never used PIC in practically and never used it with MATLAB...

Answer (score 0):

AVR Arduino boards are well supported by MatLab:

- http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/arduino-matlab.html
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-IO-Matlab-basic-tutorial
- http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/interfacing-matlab-and-arduino
- http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27843-arduino-io-package-slides-and-examples